# Java Garbage collection eligibility

Tags: java

I am preparing for OCJP exam. I am giving a mock test. Here is a code snippet.

```
public class GC {
    private Object o;

    private void doSomethingElse(Object obj) {
        o = obj;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        Object obj = new Object(); // Line 5
        doSomethingElse(obj);      // Line 6
        obj = new Object();        // Line 7
        doSomethingElse(null);     // Line 8
        obj = null;                // Line 9
    }
}
```

When the doSomething method is called, after which line does the Object obj become available for garbage collection?

I know the answer is Line 9 , however according to  the exam simulator it is line 8 ?  I am not sure who is right ?

Comment: It's creating 2 objects, obj is a var not object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simulator is right. In line 7, you overwrite the local hard reference to the instance, so the code in line 9 makes the second `Object` eligible for GC. The first one becomes eligible with line 8.

Longer explanation:

Line 5: create `inst1` and assign to `obj`
Line 6: put `inst1` into `this.o`. There are now two hard references to `inst1`
Line 7: create `inst2` and assign to `obj`. `this.o` still points to `inst1`
Line 8: Clear reference `this.o`, make `inst1` available for GC
Line 9: Clear reference `obj`, make `inst2` available for GC

Comment: The second object will be eligible on Line 8 as well. It's not reachable after line 8 (after line 7 really).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That depends on JIT optimizations and the GC implementation. In theory, the local stack still has a hard link.

Comment: Right, if we're talking specification and _eligibility_, it's eligible the moment no _continuing computation_ can access it_. In this program, none can after line 7.

Answer (score 1):

The object created in line 5 gets eligible for garbage collection after line 8 and the one created in 7 gets eligible for garbage collection in line 9.